# Accessing github activities on organizational account via GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I wrote some scripts for evaluating github activities of my students ([Link](https://github.com/TUBAF-IFI-DiPiT/github2pandas)) based on GitHub API. Authentication is implemented by a GitHub Token. Everything works fine if the scripts run locally.

If I include them in a GitHub Action I got a strange behavior ... for repositories assigned to my personal account, GitHub answered requests as expected. But if I address repos belonging to our organization, I receive an error

```
Github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"}
```

Again, on my PC the script works for both cases. Do I permit such GitHub Workflow based script operations separately?

Comment: Could you share the workflow `.yml` file you used to run the script in your question please?

Comment: Dear GuiFalourd, many thanks for your offer! But in the meantime I recognized that it was my fault and realized that two different tokens exist. Due to the fact that I used an environment variable on my PC I was not aware of.

Comment: Great! You should answer your question with your solution, that way if someone else gets the same issue, he will know how to solve it :)